# MouseClick event on Button doesnt fire when MouseEnter/Leave and Hover events are in-place (devexpress button)

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a button called "Discard changes" for grid row. And there is Validate row handler which is called when row is about to loose focus and it pop-ups a msg if chanegs are invalid.

When user clicks discard I want the new row to be discarded straightaway.

But on clicking discard, before the click event handler, validate row handler is being called, hence popping up that invalid entry message (if any cell value is invalid), where i want the button click to be called first.

I thought on How to detect that the row lost focus because of discard button click.

So I tried Enter and leave events of this button where I set/unset a variable so that inside Validate I just do nothing if this variable is set.

But On using the enter/leave events, The actual click event is not getting fired at all. either the validate nor click are fired. Some sort of infinite Enter/Leave might be happening. Can someone help.

Comment: Have you tried to put a break point in your click event to see if it is even being called?

Comment: ofcourse. that is the first thing i would do, not depending on verifying the functionality of click occuring.

Comment: Maybe you evaluated the sender and eventargs also? nothing wrond there?

Comment: I narrowed down by debugging. problem is not related to enter/leave. it is between grid and button. i will modify the question accordingly in a  while. thanks for your follow up.

Comment: post some code as to what you are doing on those event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SimpleButton, set its [AllowFocus](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsSimpleButton_AllowFocustopic) property to false. This trick will help you get rid of redundant validation.